# How to get most presented items in a List of c#?

Tags: c#, list

I know in c#, to get a item from a list can use FirstOrDefault() or other functions. I am looking for a function can get most presented items from a List.

For example:

```
{ "a" , "a" , "a" , "b" }.MostPresents() => "a"
```

Is there a default function in c# (asp.net 4.0) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var MostCommonItem = list.GroupBy(item => item)
                         .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                         .Select(g => g.Key).First();
```

Comment: Sorting makes this `O(n log n)` when you can do it in `O(n)`.

Comment: good point. if this was a huge list, the complexity would def. play a factor.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a default function in c# (asp.net 4.0) for this?

No, but you can slap together some LINQ and get it pretty quickly.

```
var mostFrequent = sequence.GroupBy(x => x)
                           .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                           .MaxBy(x => x.Count)
                           .Key;
```

Here, I am using [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=84).